# Google Play Store Copyright Law?

Tags: android, google-play

I am currently developing a travel guide app & I am using pictures that I found on google.

My question is that **if** I mention the name of the photographer who took that picture.(Will my app get removed from google play store or will I be violating their rules?). & And if my app will not be removed (but if again) I don't find the name of the photographer can I just add Like I.E. (Image By : Google)?

And also I will also use Admob in the app (Not on/in the images!) only in the screens.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Voting to close as a law question that should be answered by Google.

Comment: Legal advice is off topic to Stack Overflow, probably you need to consult a lawyer not a random person from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different type of Licensing in intellectual property.

1. Which you can use for free, distribute for free also modify it.
2. You can use it for free, but can not distribute it or modify it.
3. You can use it for free and distribute it but you have to mention the original creator.

I recommend you only include those images

1. Which are free to use and distribute. (No need to mention creator)
2. Which are free to use and distribute but you have to credit the original creator. (Credit the original creator)
3. Do not use other images. (Even though you may not be subjected to copyright at first or Play Store might give you green light to publish the app, later on as your app grows you might get into trouble).

So you have limitation of which images you can use, and limitation is not always bad. This might make your even more precise and better.